# How to build string in xml format using Xquery or XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, xquery, cdata

I wish to frame the string request in wso2esb for that I am using Xquery. I have tried with string function in xquery but I am getting errors my xquery is like this.
I wish to send this xml format to my client

```
<kls:XInput>
    <kls:XData>
         <DATA>
 <REQUEST ID_VALUE="5" NAME_VALUE="khfgd" MESSAGE_VALUE="Who" USER_TYPE="Daimond" PHNO_VALUE="65879541212" ></REQUEST>
</DATA>
  </kls:XData>
 </kls:XInput>
```

For above xml request i have used below xquery to get the deisre xml request

```
<x xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
  declare namespace env="http://eai.googl.afr/Envelope";
  declare namespace kls="http://eai.klsdop.inso/klsservice";
  declare variable $Id as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Name as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $Message as xs:string+ external;
  declare variable $PHNO as xs:string+ external;

  element{'kls:XInput'}{
  element{'kls:XData'}{string(
  <DATA>      
    <REQUEST ID_VALUE="{$Id}" NAME_VALUE="{$Name}" MESSAGE_VALUE="{$Message}" USER_TYPE="Daimond" PHNO_VALUE="{$PHNO}" ></REQUEST>
</DATA>)
  }
  }
```

above parameters I am passing in my code and those reaching as well but unable to build the xquery.
But I am getting error in my server like this.Because every time values will change.

```
[2014-11-14 16:23:44,375] ERROR - XQueryMediator Error during the querying No ex
ternal variable named **Id** exists in the query
javax.xml.xquery.XQException: No external variable named **Id** exists in the qu
ery
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDynamicContext.bindExternalVariable(SaxonXQDy
namicContext.java:225)
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDynamicContext.bindObject(SaxonXQDynamicConte
xt.java:154)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.bindVariable(XQuer
yMediator.java:594)
```

Is there any way to solve the this in XSLT means adding CDATA in XSLT or Xquery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error indicates you're  not handing over the external variables (say: parameters). The input document misses the namespace declaration for the prefix used. Your code contains unmatched opening tags. At least to me it is unclear what you're trying to do; you're fighting with XQuery errors, and at the same time want to include CDATA nodes. Please read [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for what's important in a good question.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your XQUERY, I think that root element '**x**' have no namespace. However, I can see above that you have associated it with namespace "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" : remove it and try again

Comment: Thank you for replay but that is default namespace of wso2esb synapse I have not mentioned it.comes automatically with every xquery